# Does every isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ send some basis to its dual basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that I have a vector space isomorphism $\theta: V \to V^*$ where $V$ is any vector space (probably over $\mathbb{C}$ is required) and $V^*$ is its dual space. Is it always possible to find a basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ of $V$ such that $\theta(v_i) = v_i^*$ for every $i$? (Here $v_i^*$ denotes the dual of $v_i$ with respect to this basis; that is, we define $v_i^*(v_j) = 1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.)

I think it will be possible to proceed by induction as long as I can find even one $v \in V$ such that $\theta(v)(v) \neq 0$. So far I can't even do this much.

Comment: I think this question ultimately reduces to "Let V be a finite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb C$ and let $b$ be a non-degenerate bilinear form, does there exist an orthogonal basis", and this is indeed the case.

Comment: Is that actually true for all non-degenerate bilinear forms? We don't need it to be symmetric?

Comment: @AlexG. No your observation is correct. Only symmetric bilinear forms (and exactly these) can be unitariyly diagonalized.

Comment: Yes I should have added the word symmetric to that sentence. But then it is still true.

Comment: @Myself Except that we can't assume the bilinear form in question actually is symmetric...

Comment: Oh you're right! Then I guess the obstruction should somehow come from a Jordan block $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Let me think if I can make that more precise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another counterexample is the determinant. Let $V=\mathbb{C}^2$, define $\theta(v):V\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ as $\theta(v)(x)=det(v,x)$.